# wordpress перегружает сервер после публикации поста

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 3.4.2
После публикации поста, сервер укладывается бесконечными запросами [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел проблемную строку:

```
wp_schedule_single_event (time (), 'do_pings');
```

В _publish_post_hook (/wp-includes/post.php)

Если ее закомментировать, проблема исчезает. Как решить это по нормальному? Во всем гугле ничего подобного нет. В настройках все, что связано с xml-rpc и pingback отключено

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO! Переведите пожалуйста вопрос на русский.

Comment: Пардон, не туда. Перевел.

Comment: 1. Не нужно ТЕСТЫ приводить скринами. 2. не нужно пользоваться темами и планинами с помоек. Есть оф каталог с тысячами проверенных, безопасных тем https://wordpress.org/themes/ и плагинов https://wordpress.org/plugins

Comment: Зачем вам ядро WordPress **5-летней давности**, да ещё с широко известными уязвимостями? Вы что, специально ищете себе проблемы?

Comment: @SeVlad, тему и плагины я проверил в первую очередь. Проблема не в них. Более того, эта тема и эти плагины использовались уже не один год на этом сайте, который давно имеет не маленькую посещаемость. Устанавливался чистый вп и проблема появляется только тогда, когда подключается эта база данных. По логике, что-то не так в настройках.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, если бы можно было обновить его, я бы это сделал. Сайт очень старый и посещаемый. Клиент не станет обновлять его. И проблема не в этом, так как другие его сайты продолжают работать на этой же версии. По делу есть что сказать?

Comment: А что значит - "когда подключается эта база данных"? Какая - эта? У WordPress одна база данных.

Comment: Само по себе ничего не случается. Поэтому - либо сайт ваш хакнули через давно известные уязвимости (вот почему надо обновлять ядро), либо произошли какие-то изменения на сервере (гадать сложно, например, обновили версию php).

Comment: А что у вас тут в "Настройки"->"Обсуждение" http://take.ms/mzu0V Первая галка должна быть снята

Answer (score 0):

В "Настройки"->"Обсуждение" первая галка должна быть снята.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ещё попробовать подавить все пинги таким кодом в functions.php

```
function no_ping( &$links ) {
    $links = array();
}
add_action( 'pre_ping', 'no_ping' );
```

Comment: Да и остальные галки тоже вряд ли нужны :)

Comment: @SeVlad остальные про приём. А первая - про передачу))

Comment: Да и приём не нужен :) А про комменты это я чот пограчился. да. Комметы чаще нужны.